# unity turn base script for enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, yield-return

I have a list of enemys. so i want each enemy have their turn.
First of all : 
Player turn --> enemys turn ("here each enemy move one by one untill the end then player move again"). how do i making some waiting time here and forcus on enemy turn?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
void Start()
{
     // find list enemy
    enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

}
void Update()
{
    //enemy turn reference to player. after move all enemy we change it to false to change the player turn.
    if(StaticClass.enemyTurn == true )
    {
       for(int i=0;i<enemy.length;i++)
        {
           // how do i making some waiting time here and forcus on enemy turn?
           EnemyTurn(i);
        }
    }
}


 public void EnemyTurn(int id)
{
    ChessMoveMent chessMoveScript = enemy[id].GetComponent<ChessMoveMent>();
    chessMoveScript.ProcessMove();
    id++;
    if(id>=enemy.Length)
    {
        isMove = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use StartCoroutine in this case.
Please try the below code:

```cs
public IEnumerator EnemyTurn(int id)
{
  yield return null;
  ChessMoveMent chessMoveScript = enemy[id].GetComponent<ChessMoveMent>();
  chessMoveScript.ProcessMove();
  id++;
  if(id>=enemy.Length)
  {
    isMove = false;
  }
}
```

When you want to use it, please use with "StartCoroutine()"

```
StartCoroutine(EnemyTurn(i));
```

More details [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a coordinator, who tells the participants when it's their turn.

```
public class GameCoordinator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Participant> participants;
    private int currentParticipantIdx = -1;

    private Participant CurrentParticipant
    {
        get { return participants[currentParticipantIdx]; }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        PlayNextMove();
    }

    private void PlayNextMove()
    {
        ProceedToNextParticipant();

        CurrentParticipant.OnMoveCompleted += OnMoveCompleted;
        CurrentParticipant.BeginMove();
    }

    private void OnMoveCompleted()
    {
        CurrentParticipant.OnMoveCompleted -= OnMoveCompleted;
        StartCoroutine(PlayNextMoveIn(2.0f));
    }

    private IEnumerator PlayNextMoveIn(float countdown)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(countdown);
        PlayNextMove();
    }

    private void ProceedToNextParticipant()
    {
        ++currentParticipantIdx;
        if (currentParticipantIdx == participants.Count)
            currentParticipantIdx = 0;
    }
}

public class Participant : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action OnMoveCompleted;

    public void BeginMove()
    {
        //
    }
}
```